# Catch video from wifi source

Tags: video-streaming

Simply a want to see on VLC (or similar software on windows) a streaming video that is generated by a drone connected to the PC via wifi.

- Drone: "Bugs 2W"
- Android app to do this: "Bugs go"

I try to install Android emulator on my win10 and it found: i play app and see video..but it is expensive! (some users with older PCs told me that streaming is slow)

Can i catch the video streaming and show it on VLC? What is the method to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use the ffmpeg command to create stream, the url on which you stream can be used to display the video in vlc.

You can use this command for streaming:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f mjpeg udp://IP_ADDRESS:PORT
```

Further use this command to view the stream:

```
vlc udp://@IP_ADDRESS:PORT
```